# Can I store multiple private keys in one Putty PPK file?

Tags: ssh, putty, pageant

I have multiple accounts on a server, say for example

- red
- webadmin
- testuser

At the moment I have private keys for these in separate PPK files. I have shortcuts to these on the desktop - so clicking the desktop icon launches Pageant and prompts for a password. After doing this for each PPK file, I can log in and out of the server(s) multiple times during the day using various user-ids without entering passwords. So far so good.

Could I streamline this further by somehow combining all these PPK files into a single PPK file? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can, however, pass multiple keys to `pageant` at once; e.g. as a batch script:

```
pageant *.ppk
```

When asked to add multiple keys, Pageant will automatically try to use the same passphrase for all of them, and will ask otherwise.

Comment: This does not work under Windows (putty-0.80). `pageant.exe *.ppk` results in an error, and `pageant.exe key1.ppk key2.ppk` only opens the first file, `key1.ppk`.